# Render order according to hierarchy in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to understand how Unity decides what to draw first in a 2D game. I could just give everything an order in layer, but I have so many objects that it would be so much easier if it was just drawing in the order of the hierarchy. I could write a script that gives every object its index, but I also want to see it in editor.
So the question is, is there an option that I can check so that it uses the order in the hierarchy window as the default sorting order?

Comment: As long as two objects are on the same render queue and use the default lessEqual Ztesting order then the draw order is the same as the hierachy, meaning that objects at the top of your hierarchy are drawn first (at the back), and the objects at the bottom are drawn last (on the top) If you change the Render Queue to something higher it will pull the object to the front depending on the value in the queue. More info in the docs here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still no luck. I didn’t change anything on the sprite settings, so shouldn’t they be on the same render queue and use the default Ztesting?
Unexpected: https://ibb.co/P4v6ynj
Expected: https://ibb.co/Y0hYq4W

Comment: Those two images appear to be the same besides the red circle, did you upload the wrong image? Also could you include a screenshot of the inspector for those two objects?

Comment: In the image with the red circle, walnut comes after cashew in the hierarchy, so I would expect it to be drawn over it. Inspector: https://ibb.co/d0V6N1Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last screenshot I could see you are using SpriteRenderer.

The short answer to the question "is there an option that I can check so that it uses the order in the hierarchy window as the default sorting order?" would be no, there isn't by default*.

Sprite renderers calculates which object is in front of others in one of two ways:

1. By using the distance to the camera, this will draw the objects closest to the camera on top of the rest of the objects in that same `order in layer`, as per the [docs:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html)

> Sprite Sort Point
>   This property is only available when the Sprite Renderer’s Draw Mode is set to Simple.
>
> In a 2D project, the Main Camera is set to Orthographic Projection mode by default. In this mode, Unity renders Sprites in the order of their their distance to the camera, along the direction of the Camera’s view.

If you want to keep everything on the same sorting layer/order in layer you can change the order in which the objects appear by moving one of the two objects further away from the camera (this is probably further down the `z` axis). For example if your Cashew is on `z = 0`, and you place the walnut on `z = 1` then the cashew will be drawn on top of the walnut. If Cashew is on `z=0` and the walnut is on `z = -1` then the walnut will be draw on top (Since negative is *closer* to the camera). If both of the objects are on `z - 0` they are both equally as far away from the camera, so it becomes a coin toss for which object gets drawn in front, as it does not take into account the hierarchy.

2. The second way the order can be changed is by creating different `sorting layers`, and adjusting the `order in layer` in the `sprite renderer` component. But you already figured that out.

*However, that doesn't mean it cannot be done, technically... 
If you feel adventurous there is nothing stopping you from making an editor script that automates setting the `order in layer` for you based on the position in the hierarchy. This script would loop through all the objects in your hierarchy, grab the index of the object in the hierarchy, and assign the index to the Order in Layer.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I will probably go with the asterisk-way. I just don’t see the point in assigning every single object when the information is already there, just Unity ignoring it.

Comment: @Philipp yeah it would be neat if something like this was supported natively, might be someone already made something for it, so check the asset store. No use in re-inventing the wheel :) If this answer was useful and answered your question please accept it by clicking the little checkmark on the top left of the answer. This way people in the future can also find it more easily if they have a similar question.

Comment: I just use this now:

`[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class UnityHelper : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update(){
        foreach (SpriteRenderer sr in FindObjectsOfType<SpriteRenderer>()){
            sr.sortingOrder = sr.transform.GetSiblingIndex();
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Unity has such feature (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html).

Usually you shall define some Sorting Layers:

- far background
- background
- foreground

and assign Sprite Renderer of each sprite to one of Sorting Layers